# Find all real solutions for the system: $x^3=y+y^5$, $y^5=z+z^7$, $z^7=x+x^3.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, systems-of-equations

> Given: $$\left\{
> \begin{array}{l}
> x^3=y+y^5\\ 
> y^5=z+z^7\\
> z^7=x+x^3 
> \end{array}
> \right. 
> $$
>   Find: all real solutions for the system.

From a book on preparation for math contests. The answer states there is just one solution. My problem is showing that this is indeed the case.

**My attempt:** it is easy to see that one solution is $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$. And, adding the equations, we get to $x+y+z=0$. But my problem is showing that this solution is indeed unique, if the answer provided in the book is right.

Hints and answers are appreciated. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: $$y^5=x^3-y=z+x+x^3\implies x+y+z=0$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $x>0$.

Hence, $z^7=x(1+x^2)>0$, which gives $z>0$.

Also, $y^5=z(1+z^6)>0$, which gives $y>0$.

But summing of all equations gives $x+y+z=0$, which is a contradiction.

By the same way we can get a contradiction for $x<0$.

Thus, $x=0$ and from here we obtain $x=y=z=0.$

Comment: Thanks a lot (+1)... as this question appeared in a chapter on inequalities I should have had that as a hint... instead I thought the problem was misplaced :). As always I learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: @bluemaster You are welcome!

Comment: Very neat solution! I'm just not sure why you need to factor $x$ and $z$ in the expressions for $z^7$ and $y^5$. Doesn't $x>0$ and $z^7 = x+x^3$ directly imply $z>0$ (and similar for $y$)?

Comment: Yes we can use that $f(x)=x^3+x$, $g(x)=x^7+x$ and $h(x)=x^5+x$ they increase.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying the three equations gives $x^3 y^5 z^7 = x y z (1+x^2)(1+y^4)(1+z^6)\,$.

If $xyz \ne 0$ then it follows that $x^2 y^4 z^6 = (1+x^2)(1+y^4)(1+z^6)\,$, but the latter is not possible since $0 \le x^2 \lt 1+ x^2, 0 \le y^4 \lt 1+y^4, 0 \le z^6 \lt 1+ z^6\,$.

Therefore $xyz=0\,$, and it is easy to show that any one of $x,y,z$ being $0$ implies *all* of them being $0$.